# Return type match with auto and friend function

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, friend, auto

So I was answering this question: *[Define friend function template of class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882049/define-friend-function-template-of-class-template/37882233)*, and I found some "weird" behavior from g++ (5.3) and clang (3.8):

Let's assume the following template:

```
template<int M>
struct test {
private:
    int value;

    template<int U, int K>
    friend test<K> foo (test<U> const t);
};

template <int M, int N = 2 * M>
test<N> foo (test<M> const t) {
    test<N> r;
    r.value = t.value;
    return r;
}

int main(){
    test<1> t;
    foo(t);
}
```

This compile with both compiler (as expected - If this should not compile, feel free to comment and explain why).

If I change things to:

```
template<int U, int K>
friend auto foo(test<U> const t);

template <int M, int N = 2 * M>
auto foo (test<M> const t) { /* ... */ }
```

This compile with g++ but not with clang, and if I set one to `auto` and the other one to a specific value, e.g.:

```
template<int U, int K>
friend test<K> foo(test<U> const t);

template <int M, int N = 2 * M>
auto foo (test<M> const t) { /* ... */ }

// or:

template<int U, int K>
friend auto foo(test<U> const t);

template <int M, int N = 2 * M>
test<N> foo (test<M> const t) { /* ... */ }
```

Both compiler reject the code saying that:

> error: 'int test<2>::value' is private

My two related questions are:

- Which compiler is right for the first case (`auto` for both declaration/definition)?
- Why is not possible to use `auto` when defining the function and `test<K>` when declaring the friendship?

Or in one question: **What are the rules about `auto` for friend function declarations when the function is defined outside the class?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [[dcl.spec.auto]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#13):

> Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template
>   with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type shall also
>   use that placeholder, not a deduced type.

I.e. if the friend declaration uses `auto` and the second declaration does not, they don't match. The other way around is guaranteed by [core issue 2081](http://wg21.link/cwg2081). Finally, if both use `auto`, the declarations should indeed match as per [[temp.over.link]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#6), so Clang is incorrect in that case.